# Images not showing in WinUI 3 Button

Tags: image, xaml, button, winui-3

I can't seem to make my WinUI 3 Button display an image.

My project is a packaged C# WinUI 3 desktop application.

Here is my XAML code (copied almost directly from the Microsoft docs):

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" AutomationProperties.Name="Pie">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="/Assets/settings-gear.png" Height="52"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Slices" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

And I'm not using any C# code on it, so that isn't the problem.

Yet my button looks like this:
[image: Button screenshot]

Here's the `.png` file I'm using as an icon:
[image: Icon]

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Works fine for me https://i.imgur.com/CIa1JWp.png You've probably something ambiant that messes it up, like the `Style` property, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier Nope. I'm using your code, and now I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iWIU.png).

Comment: Update WinAppSDK to 1.3 and please post a reproducible sample instead of noping people who try to help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier Where do I find this info?

Comment: [Latest downloads for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads).  It may be that the image file is not properly referenced, you can try to use the default logo image for testing. Can it be displayed normally? `<Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png" Height="52"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Go to the **Solution Explorer** and right-click *settings-gear.png* and select **Properties**.
2. In the **Properties** section, change the **Build Action** from *None* to *Content*.

Comment: Will try as soon as possible as I'm on vacation currently and don't have my laptop with me.